# Find error-ed column name in Oracle not null constraint

Tags: sql, oracle, ddl, check-constraints

I have a table with multiple NOT NULL columns. When I insert data with NULL value in NOT NULL columns, NOT NULL constraint error ORA-01400 is raised, but Column name in error message is blank.

```
ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ()
```

Why I cannot see error-ed column name and What can be work around to get column name in error message as below?

```
ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("APPS"."MY_TABLE_NAME"."FIRST_NAME")
```

Table Example :

```
create table apps.my_table_data
(
  id  number,
  first_name varchar2(50) not null,
  last_name varchar2(50) not null,
  district_name varchar2(50) not null
);
```

I also tried giving constraint explicit name:

```
create table apps.my_table_data
(
  id number,
  first_name varchar2(50) constraint my_table_date_first_name not null,
  last_name varchar2(50) constraint my_table_date_last_name not null,
  district_name varchar2(50) constraint my_table_date_district_nm not null
  status  varchar2(30 char),
)
```

But still I cannot see error-ed column name in error message.

Comment: Can you tell us what the table definition looks like? Usually oracle does tell you the column name in the error.

Comment: @ruudvan - I have added table definition in my question. Thanks